# Display number of records based on user input in js. Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

Hi i want to display according to numberofRec value, it can be 10,20,30. Those many records should be there in currentList attribute.
How to achieve this?

```
NumberofRecords: function(component, numberofRec, recordToDisply) {
    var records = component.get("v.allAccounts");
    var  pageNumber = component.get("v.pageNumber");
    alert('pageNumber'+pageNumber); // current page
    var pageRecords = records.slice((pageNumber-1)*10, pageNumber*10);
    alert('pageRecords'+pageRecords); // current 
    component.set("v.currentList", pageRecords);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just replace 10 with numberofRec:

```
NumberofRecords: function(component, numberofRec, recordToDisply) {
    var records = component.get("v.allAccounts");
    var  pageNumber = component.get("v.pageNumber");
    alert('pageNumber'+pageNumber); // current page
    var pageRecords = records.slice((pageNumber-1)*numberofRec, pageNumber*numberofRec);
    alert('pageRecords'+pageRecords); // current 
    component.set("v.currentList", pageRecords);
}
```